# Get parent object, by nested property

Tags: javascript

I have the following object, an array with databases, each containing a collection of tables, each containing a collection of columns.

[image: Console Output]

I want to obtain the parent table, given the Id of a column and tried to avoid iterating over the collection. Just a very simple clean single line.

I was initially trying but quickly was challenged by the fact Tables is not an array but a collection which doesn't support .some statements.

```
let table = schema.find((database,index) => database.Tables.some((column,index) => column.Id === 1234));
```

Is there a smart way or conversion trick that I have overlooked that prevents me from having to iterate the entire structure?

Comment: [Please don't use images for code, data structures or log files](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9078341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.values()` to get an array of columns from your Tables object:

```
let table = schema.find(database => Object.values(database.Tables).some(column => column.Id === 1234));
```

Alternately, you could use `Object.keys()` and write it like this:

```
let table = schema.find(database => Object.keys(database.Tables)
                                          .some(columnName => database.Tables[columnName].Id === 1234));
```

Comment: I actually did have to get a nested object. So I had to start the search based on the initial result, and then use the Tables collection again to find what I was looking for. With the following I will get the result.

``` lang-js
let column = Object.values(schema.find((database) => Object.values(database.Tables).some((column) => column.Id === event.srcElement.id)).Tables).find((column) => column.Id === event.srcElement.id);
console.log(column);
```

Comment: @MichaSchopman That's one ugly `find()`! Nested objects can confuse you pretty good if you aren't careful (and doing a one-liner sometimes makes it worse), but I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Ugly can be beautiful sometimes ;)